# Gradle: Include dynamically generated file in build?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

During my gradle build, I generate a temporary `buildinfo.properties` file containing things like Git commit info, build time, etc. I would like to include this file in my output `*.jar` / `*.war` files as a resource. However, I **do not want** to put this file in my project `src/` folder (this would require fiddling with `.gitignore` and in general it just seems unnecessary to me). Ideally, the developer shouldn't even see this file at all, it should just be contained in the output archive.

How would you include a dynamically generated text file in a Gradle build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add that file in a `jar` task (Kotin DSL):

```
tasks {
    val jar by getting(Jar::class) {
        from("build/buildinfo.properties")
    }
}
```

It will add `build/buildinfo.properties` file (assuming you generate it there with another taks) to the root of your JAR.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically generated file, standard gradle way to process resources is the gradle task called processResources. You can do something like this:

```
processResources {
      dependsOn taskThatGeneratesYourBuildinfo
      from("build/buildinfo.properties") {
          into("desired/path/in/jar")
      }
}
```